# When To Observe/Unobserve Events

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, notifications

I am currently using a UINavigationController based flow:

```
Events +-> Event Input
       |
       +-> People -> People Input
```

The model underlying Events and People fires notifications when the collection changes. I'm hooking up the observers in `viewWillAppear:animated:` and unhooking them in `viewWillDisappear`. This all seems fine, but what I really want is for the observer for people to be hooked up when I transition from Events to People and stay hooked up until I transition back to Events. That way, even when People Input hides People, the notification will be handled so I can update my list.

Note: *I am not using segues.*

Where are the best places to hook up the observers and unhook them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I chose to fix this was to compare the current controller to the `navigationController` collection of `viewController`s. If it is not contained in this collection, then I know the view was popped and I can unobserve events. I make this test in `viewDidDisappear`.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can enlarge the time scope from viewDidLoad for observing to dealloc for unobserving. Then you can update your content at the sole condition that the view actually exists.